# How to insert json response data in snowflake database more efficiently?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently looping through a json response and inserting each row one by one.

This is very slow even for a few thousand rows of data insert.

What is the most efficient way to insert the data?

Here is my code.

```
from module import usr, pwd, acct, db, schem, api_key
import snowflake.connector
import datetime

end_point = 'users'

def snowflake_connect():
    global cursor, mydb
    mydb = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=usr,
        password=pwd,
        account=acct,
        database=db,
        schema=schem,
    )

def snowflake_insert(id, activated, name):
    global cursor
    snowflake_connect()
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO USERS(ID, ACTIVATED, NAME) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
    insert_tuple = (id, activated, name)
    cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple)
    return cursor

def get_users():
    url = 'https://company.pipedrive.com/v1/{}?&api_token={}'.format(end_point,api_key)
    response = requests.request("GET", url).json()
    read_users(response)

def read_users(response):   
    for data in response['data']:
        id = data['id']
        activated = data['activated']
        name = data['name']     
        snowflake_insert(id, activated, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    snowflake_truncate()
    get_users()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: Check out the `COPY INTO` command. Here's a thread from the Snowflake support forums about this exact process. https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z000090I9u4SAC/should-i-prefer-copy-over-insert-into

Comment: Exactly, staging the json files then copying them into the table could save you alot of time. The loading semi-structured data reference in the documentation is another resource I would recommend. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/semistructured-intro.html#loading-semi-structured-data and particularly FLATTEN and Variants https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-flatten.html

Answer (score 2):

As noted by [others in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901246/how-to-insert-json-response-data-in-snowflake-database-more-efficiently#comment105931291_59901246), to get the highest efficiency, especially for a continual load, load your formatted data files directly into Snowflake instead of using `INSERT` statements as a best-practice.

However, the code in description can also be further improved to minimise overheads created per inserted row. A few key observations:

- The code is creating a new `connection` object every insert, this is unnecessary.
- Since the intention is to only run `INSERT` statements that do not need isolation, the `cursor` object [can be reused](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects).
- Multiple values can be sent per `INSERT` statement, [using the multi-value feature](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#usage-notes), or expressed in a simpler way using [`cursor.executemany(…)`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects).
- Switch to using `qmark (?)` parameter formatting to [avoid potential SQL injection](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#avoid-sql-injection-attacks).

A modified code version:

```py
from module import usr, pwd, acct, db, schem, api_key
import snowflake.connector
import datetime

end_point = 'users'
MYDB = None

def snowflake_connect():
    if MYDB is None:
        MYDB = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=usr,
            password=pwd,
            account=acct,
            database=db,
            schema=schem,
        )

def snowflake_insert_all(rows):
    snowflake_connect()
    cursor = MYDB.cursor()
    sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO USERS(ID, ACTIVATED, NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, rows)
    return cursor

def get_users():
    url = 'https://company.pipedrive.com/v1/{}?&api_token={}'.format(end_point,api_key)
    response = requests.request("GET", url).json()
    read_users(response)

def read_users(response):
    # 
    all_data = [(data['id'], data['activated'], data['name']) for data in response['data']]
    snowflake_insert_all(all_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    snowflake_truncate()
    get_users()
    if MYDB is not None:
      MYDB.close()
```

**Note**: I've only focussed on improving the Snowflake and DB-API interaction portions here but in general there's other faults (variable and method naming, unnecessary use of globals, resource handling, etc.) in the way this script is written that can use help from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), if you're looking to improve your program further.